# How to plot non-linear decision boundaries with a grid in R?

Tags: r, plot

I find this particular graph in [ISLR](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) ([Figure 2.13](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Chapter2/2.13.pdf)) or [ESL](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) very well done. I can't guess how the authors would have made this in R. I know how to get the orange and blue points very easily. The main confusion is the background dots and the purple line.

Any ideas?[image: Fig 2.13, ISLR]

Here is some sample code to get the yellow and orange points with a grey grid. How do I get an arbitrary non-linear curve in purple and then color the grid according to the curve?

```
set.seed(pi)
points = replicate(100, runif(2))
pointsColored = ifelse(apply(points, 2, sum) <= 1, "orange", "blue")
# Confound some
pointsColored[sample.int(length(pointsColored), 10)] = "orange"
plot(x=points[1, ], y=points[2, ])
grid(nx=100, ny=100)
# Plot points over the grid.
points(x=points[1, ], y=points[2, ], col=pointsColored)
```

Comment: Hmm... downvote? Because I have not provided an attempt of my own?

Comment: Provide what you have tried with your sample data...

Comment: It's hard to gauge what's happening in this plot since some points cross over the line that seems to distinguish the color change. Sample data and what you've tried so far would help.

Comment: It would be good to provide some context, e.g., from the text surrounding Figure 2.13 in ISLR. This is a two-dimensional classification problem with two classes. The circles are the training data. The dots show the predictions of a Bayes classifier based on some machine learning algorithm. The dashed line is the Bayes decision boundary. The main problem really is to extract the decision boundary from whatever ML algorithm you are using. The dots are easy, using something along `dots <- expand.grid(...)` and `plot(..., col=predict(dots))`.

Comment: @StephanKolassa: I see where you are going, but isn't there a way to plot this without actually simulating a classification exercise?

Comment: So then you're just interested in an arbitrarily located line?

Comment: "Coloring the grid according to a curve" is not completely trivial... Is your curve guaranteed not to cross itself? Is your curve connected? (Decision boundaries, e.g. for kNN with small k, can consist of multiple curves.) I think there are really two problems here: (1) computational geometry, (2) the actual plotting in R once the CG aspect is solved. Problem (2) may be trivial once you have solved (1), but the SO:R tag is probably not the best venue to ask about (1).

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/21572) post on stats.stackexchange.com. Searching for "non-linear decision boundary" might turn up more results but on first glance this one seems to be exactly what you're after.

Comment: The title of this post should be changed to describe the kind of plot in question.  Internet search engines seem to emphasize the title.  The existing title will be of no value to people attempting to locate help in creating similar plots in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I indicated in my comment, a solution was provided by @chl [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/21572) on stats.stackexchange.com. Here it is, applied to your data set.

```
library(class)
set.seed(pi)
X <- t(replicate(1000, runif(2)))
g <- ifelse(apply(X, 1, sum) <= 1, 0, 1)
xnew <- cbind(rep(seq(0, 1, length.out=50), 50),
              rep(seq(0, 1, length.out=50), each=50))
m <- knn(X, xnew, g, k=15, prob=TRUE)
prob <- attr(m, "prob")
prob <- ifelse(m=="1", prob, 1-prob)
prob15 <- matrix(prob, 50)
par(mar=rep(3, 4))
contour(unique(xnew[, 1]), unique(xnew[, 2]), prob15, levels=0.5, 
        labels="", xlab='', ylab='', axes=FALSE, lwd=2.5, asp=1)
title(xlab=expression(italic('X')[1]), ylab=expression(italic('X')[2]), 
      line=1, family='serif', cex.lab=1.5)
points(X, bg=ifelse(g==1, "#CA002070", "#0571B070"), pch=21)
gd <- expand.grid(x=unique(xnew[, 1]), y=unique(xnew[, 2]))
points(gd, pch=20, cex=0.4, col=ifelse(prob15 > 0.5, "#CA0020", "#0571B0"))
box()
```

[image: decision boundary]

(UPDATE: I changed the colour palette because the blue/yellow/purple thing was pretty hideous.)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

This was my silly attempt at approximation. Clearly the issues raised by @StephenKolassa are valid and not handled by this approximation.

```
myCurve1 = function (x)
  abs(x[[1]] * sin(x[[1]]) + x[[2]] * sin(x[[2]]))
myCurve2 = function (x)
  abs(x[[1]] * cos(x[[1]]) + x[[2]] * cos(x[[2]]))
myCurve3 = function (x)
  abs(x[[1]] * tan(x[[1]]) + x[[2]] * tan(x[[2]]))

tmp = function (myCurve, seed=99) {
  set.seed(seed)
  points = replicate(100, runif(2))
  colors = ifelse(apply(points, 2, myCurve) > 0.5, "orange", "blue")
  # Confound some
  swapInts = sample.int(length(colors), 6)
  for (i in swapInts) {
    if (colors[[i]] == "orange") {
      colors[[i]] = "blue"
    } else {
      colors[[i]] = "orange"
    }
  }
  gridPoints = seq(0, 1, 0.005)
  gridPoints = as.matrix(expand.grid(gridPoints, gridPoints))
  gridColors = vector("character", nrow(gridPoints))
  gridPch = vector("character", nrow(gridPoints))
  for (i in 1:nrow(gridPoints)) {
    val = myCurve(gridPoints[i, ])
    if (val > 0.505) {
      gridColors[[i]] = "orange"
      gridPch[[i]] = "."
    } else if (val < 0.495) {
      gridColors[[i]] = "blue"
      gridPch[[i]] = "."
    } else {
      gridColors[[i]] = "purple"
      gridPch[[i]] = "*"
    }
  }
  plot(x=gridPoints[ , 1], y=gridPoints[ , 2], col=gridColors, pch=gridPch)
  points(x=points[1, ], y=points[2, ], col=colors, lwd=2)
}

par(mfrow=c(1, 3))
tmp(myCurve1)
tmp(myCurve2)
tmp(myCurve3)
```

[image]