# R: "Superimpose" (stack) plots on top of each other (ggplot2, plotly)

Tags: r, ggplot2, 3d, plotly, data-visualization

I am using the R programming language. I am trying to learn how to plot "non linear decision boundaries", such as the examples seen over here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212965/how-to-achieve-a-nonlinear-decision-boundary . I am trying to learn how to do this both in 2 Dimensions and in 3 Dimensions. I have figured out how to make the basic plots, but I am still struggling to plot the decision boundaries.

To illustrate this example, I have simulated some data. I then split this data into a training and test set. Then, I fit a statistical model (in this case, "random forest") to the training data, and have this model make predictions on the test data. To plot the results, I use a visualization algorithm called "TSNE" which facilitates visualizing large amounts of data (since I have mixed categorical and continuous data, I take the Gower Distance before doing TSNE). I can make these TSNE visualizations in 2 dimensions and in 3 dimensions. Now, I am trying to figure out how to plot the decision boundaries corresponding to the random forest model.

Below, I show the process:

First, I simulate some data:

```
#load libraries

library(cluster)
library(Rtsne)
library(dplyr)
library(randomForest)
library(caret)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(class)

#PART 1 : Create Data

#generate 4 random variables : response_variable ~ var_1 , var_2, var_3

 var_1 <- rnorm(1000,1,4)
 var_2<-rnorm(1000,10,5)
 var_3 <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05) )
 response_variable <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.9) )


#put them into a data frame called "f"
f <- data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3, response_variable)

#declare var_3 and response_variable as factors
f$response_variable = as.factor(f$response_variable)
f$var_3 = as.factor(f$var_3)

#create id
f$ID <- seq_along(f[,1])
```

Next, I split the data and run a random forest model:

```
#PART 2: random forest

#split data into train set and test set
index = createDataPartition(f$response_variable, p=0.7, list = FALSE)
train = f[index,]
test = f[-index,]

#create random forest statistical model
rf = randomForest(response_variable ~ var_1 + var_2 + var_3, data=train, ntree=20, mtry=2)

#have the model predict the test set
pred = predict(rf, test, type = "prob")
labels = as.factor(ifelse(pred[,2]>0.5, "A", "B"))
confusionMatrix(labels, test$response_variable)
```

After, I make a 2D visualization of the results:

```
#PART 3: Visualize in 2D (source: https://dpmartin42.github.io/posts/r/cluster-mixed-types)

gower_dist <- daisy(test[, -c(4,5)],
                    metric = "gower")

gower_mat <- as.matrix(gower_dist)

labels = data.frame(labels)
labels$ID = test$ID


tsne_obj <- Rtsne(gower_dist,  is_distance = TRUE)

tsne_data <- tsne_obj$Y %>%
    data.frame() %>%
    setNames(c("X", "Y")) %>%
    mutate(cluster = factor(labels$labels),
           name = labels$ID)

plot = ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y), data = tsne_data) +
    geom_point(aes(color = labels$labels))

plotly_plot = ggplotly(plot)
```

Next, I make a 3D visualization:

```
#PART 4: Visualize in 3D (source: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/441420_9a7c15988f3c4f59b2d828eb87ba1634.html)

tsne_obj_3 <- Rtsne(gower_dist, dims=3,  is_distance = TRUE)
df_m2 <- as.data.frame(tsne_obj_3$Y)


t <- list(
  family = "serif",
  size = 11,
  color = "#852E2E")

3d_plot <- plot_ly(type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'markers', colors = "Accent", color = labels$labels) %>%
  add_trace(
    x = df_m2$V1,
    y = df_m2$V2,
    z = df_m2$V3,
    marker = list(
      size = 3),
    name = labels$ID,
    text = paste("ID: ", labels$ID),
    showlegend = T
  )  %>%
  
  layout(
    title = "3d t-SNA",
    titlefont = list(
      size = 10
    ),
    paper_bgcolor = "#fffff8",
    font = t,
    xaxis = list(
      zeroline = F
    ),
    yaxis = list(
      hoverformat = '.2f',
      zeroline = F
    )
  )  

3d_plot
```

Here is where I am struggling. I want to now show the 2D decision boundary and the 3D decision boundary on top of each respective plot ("plotly_plot" and "3d_plot"). I am not able to figure out how to do this. Here are my attempts:

```
# Problem 1: interactive 2D visualization with boundary, something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052643/how-to-plot-non-linear-decision-boundaries-with-a-grid-in-r

prob <- attr(labels, "prob")
prob <- ifelse(labels$labels=="A", prob, 1-prob)
prob15 <- matrix(prob, 50)
par(mar=rep(3, 4))
contour(unique(xnew[, 1]), unique(xnew[, 2]), prob15, levels=0.5, 
        labels="", xlab='', ylab='', axes=FALSE, lwd=2.5, asp=1)
title(xlab=expression(italic('X')[1]), ylab=expression(italic('X')[2]), 
      line=1, family='serif', cex.lab=1.5)
points(X, bg=ifelse(g==1, "#CA002070", "#0571B070"), pch=21)
gd <- expand.grid(x=unique(xnew[, 1]), y=unique(xnew[, 2]))
points(gd, pch=20, cex=0.4, col=ifelse(prob15 > 0.5, "#CA0020", "#0571B0"))
box()
```

And:

```
# Problem 2: interactive 3d visualization, something like this: http://www.semspirit.com/artificial-intelligence/machine-learning/regression/support-vector-regression/support-vector-regression-in-r/

axis_1 = df_m2$V1
axis_2 = df_m2$V2
axis_3 = df_m2$V3
plot_ly(x=as.vector(axis_1),y=as.vector(axis_2),z=axis_3, type="scatter3d", mode="markers", name = "Obs", marker = list(size = 3)) %>%
add_trace(x=as.vector(axis_1),y=as.vector(axis_2),z=labels$labels, type = "mesh3d", name = "Preds")
```

Can someone please show me how to resolve these problems?
Thanks

EDIT : the 2D decision boundary can be plotted as follows, but I have not yet figured out how to make it interactive:

```
library(cluster)
library(Rtsne)
library(dplyr)

library(randomForest)
library(caret)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)


#PART 1 : Create Data

#generate 4 random variables : response_variable ~ var_1 , var_2, var_3

var_1 <- rnorm(10000,1,4)
var_2<-rnorm(10000,10,5)
var_3 <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05) )
response_variable <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.6) )


#put them into a data frame called "f"
f <- data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3, response_variable)

#declare var_3 and response_variable as factors
f$response_variable = as.factor(f$response_variable)
f$var_3 = as.factor(f$var_3)

#create id
f$ID <- seq_along(f[,1])

#PART 2: random forest

#split data into train set and test set
index = createDataPartition(f$response_variable, p=0.7, list = FALSE)
train = f[index,]
test = f[-index,]

#create random forest statistical model
rf = randomForest(response_variable ~ var_1 + var_2 + var_3, data=train, ntree=20, mtry=2)

#have the model predict the test set
pred = predict(rf, test, type = "prob")
labels = as.factor(ifelse(pred[,2]>0.5, "A", "B"))
confusionMatrix(labels, test$response_variable)

#PART 3: Visualize in 2D (source: https://dpmartin42.github.io/posts/r/cluster-mixed-types)

gower_dist <- daisy(test[, -c(4,5)],
                    metric = "gower")

gower_mat <- as.matrix(gower_dist)

labels = data.frame(labels)
labels$ID = test$ID


tsne_obj <- Rtsne(gower_dist,  is_distance = TRUE)

tsne_data <- tsne_obj$Y %>%
    data.frame() %>%
    setNames(c("X", "Y")) %>%
    mutate(cluster = factor(labels$labels),
           name = labels$ID)

plot = ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y), data = tsne_data) +
    geom_point(aes(color = labels$labels))

plotly_plot = ggplotly(plot)


a = tsne_obj$Y
a = data.frame(a)
data = a
data$class = labels$labels


decisionplot <- function(model, data, class = NULL, predict_type = "class",
                         resolution = 100, showgrid = TRUE, ...) {
    
    if(!is.null(class)) cl <- data[,class] else cl <- 1
    data <- data[,1:2]
    k <- length(unique(cl))
    
    plot(data, col = as.integer(cl)+1L, pch = as.integer(cl)+1L, ...)
    
    # make grid
    r <- sapply(data, range, na.rm = TRUE)
    xs <- seq(r[1,1], r[2,1], length.out = resolution)
    ys <- seq(r[1,2], r[2,2], length.out = resolution)
    g <- cbind(rep(xs, each=resolution), rep(ys, time = resolution))
    colnames(g) <- colnames(r)
    g <- as.data.frame(g)
    
    ### guess how to get class labels from predict
    ### (unfortunately not very consistent between models)
    p <- predict(model, g, type = predict_type)
    if(is.list(p)) p <- p$class
    p <- as.factor(p)
    
    if(showgrid) points(g, col = as.integer(p)+1L, pch = ".")
    
    z <- matrix(as.integer(p), nrow = resolution, byrow = TRUE)
    contour(xs, ys, z, add = TRUE, drawlabels = FALSE,
            lwd = 2, levels = (1:(k-1))+.5)
    
    invisible(z)
}


model <- randomForest(class ~ ., data=data, mtry=2, ntrees=500)
 final_plot = decisionplot(model, data, class = "class", main = "rf (1)")
```

Comment: I found a link that might be useful: https://michael.hahsler.net/SMU/EMIS7332/R/viz_classifier.html

Comment: I made a bit more progress - see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65406196/r-convert-regular-plot-to-ggplot-object-and-then-plotly